# Visualforce remote call not working with safari

Tags: safari, salesforce, visualforce

I am developing an application using angularjs and visualforce remote calling.

The application works right in all the browser except in Safari. When the application is run on Safari browser it is not able to communicate to the server
returning

"Unable to connect to server( Communication failed)".

## Code snippet

### Apex Controller

```
global class UsaTAevaluationCtrl{

@RemoteAction 
   public static string getkeyvalue(string username,string key)
   {
      string interviewInviteId1;
       system.debug(username+'OOOOOOOOOO'+key);
       interviewInviteId1='False';

       Tech_Screen_Invites__c t=new Tech_Screen_Invites__c();
       try
       {
          t=[select id,name from Tech_Screen_Invites__c where Name=:username];
          string recordkey=t.id;
         if(t.id!=null)
           {
              interviewInviteId1=t.id;
             recordkey=string.valueof(t.id);
              if(recordkey.length()==18)
                  recordkey=recordkey.left(15);
              if(recordkey.right(3)==key)
                 interviewInviteId1=t.id;
           }
           else
           {}
       }catch(exception e){}

    return interviewInviteId1;
   }  
}
```

### Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="UsaTAevaluationCtrl" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:form >
// include statements
....

<script>
var services = (function(){
  return function (userName, password) {   

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.UsaTAevaluationCtrl.getkeyvalue}',
                userName,
                password, 
            function (result, event){
            console.log("Result -> ", result);               
        });
        return deferred.promise();        
    }

})()

</script>
....

<div class="container" ng-app="TechEval" ng-controller="evalform" ng-init="initEvent()">

<div class="row evaluation-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row evaluation-row" ng-show="isAuthenticationSuccess">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-danger score-alert">Invalid Credentials</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row evaluation-row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="skill-title">User Name</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">                
                <div class="skill-new">
                    <input name='_username' id='userinput' ng-model='_username' required="required"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row evaluation-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"></div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="row evaluation-row">      
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="skill-title">Token</h1>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">                 
                 <div class="skill-new">
                     <input name="_password" id="passvalue" type="password" ng-model='_password' required="required"></input>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>

<div class="row btn-row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div>
             <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">                 
                 <div class="skill-new">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:92px;" ng-click="Authentication()">Submit</button>
                 </div>
             </div> 
        </div>


</div>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

### Code in Angular Controller

```
var EvalApp = angular.module('TechEval', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    EvalApp.controller('evalform', function ($scope, $log, $q) {
    $scope.Authentication = function () {
          services.getKeyValue($scope._username,
                               $scope._password,
                               function (result, event){
                     console.log("Result -> ", result);                                    
         }); 

}
}
```

### Functionality

When user enter username and password and hits submit button the remote service is to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [Supported Browsers for Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_aloha.htm&language=en_US) page, you find:

> Apple Safari versions 8.x on Mac OS X There are no configuration
> recommendations for Safari. Apple Safari on iOS isn’t supported for
> the full Salesforce site. Safari isn’t supported for:
>
> - The Salesforce console
> - Salesforce CRM Call Center built with CTI Toolkit versions below 4.0
> - Salesforce Wave Analytics

Are you sure that your OS/Safari version are compatible with it?